# In VBA, is it possible to set a range to be relative to another range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a very long script, and I'm trying to find as many shortcuts as possible. I need to set up a lot of ranges before starting. Would it be possible to replace something like:

```
Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Range2 As Range 
Dim Range3 As Range
Dim i As Long

i = 2

Set Range1 = ("D" & i)
Set Range2 = ("H" & i)
Set Range3 = ("L" & i)
```

With some like

```
Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Range2 As Range 
Dim Range3 As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim y As Long 

i = 2
y = 4

Set Range1 = ("D" & i)
Set Range2 = (Range1.Offset(,y))
Set Range3 = (Range2.Offset(,y))
```

It would be very helpful if I have 100 ranges to set, all equal distances from one another. If I were to use 100 ranges, would I need to Dim each one as I have here? Or can I do something like "Set RangeN as Range where N is every integer between 1 and 100?"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary.

```
Sub ex()
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim i As Integer, y As Integer
Dim key
y = 4
For i = 0 To 2
    dict.Add i, Range("D2").Offset(, y * i)
Next
For Each key In dict
    dict(key).Value = "test" & key
Next
End Sub
```

dict(i) will be a range and you can do whatever you normaly would with it.

Comment: This looks to be on the right track. Can you elaborate a little on what the Dim key line means, and how that relates to what the output is? Thanks.

Comment: They dim key was just for the "for each key" a little bit later, you don't have to use it, but I find it nicer than doing something like "for i=0 to dict.count-1" especially if you are not sure what your keys might be. It lets you iterate over all keys what ever they are.